# ID of Nested custom web control

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I have googled a lot today and have not found any helpful answers to my problem.

I have a web custom control (CustomControl1) that calls another web custom control (CustomControl2) as follows:

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);  

        for (int i= 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
             Panel pn = new Panel();

             Controls.Add(pn);

             CustomControl2 ct2= new CustomControl2();
             ct2.ID = "CustomControl2";

             pn.Controls.Add(rowControl);
        }
    }
```

I thought each time CustomControl2 created, it will be given the ID as {parentId} + "CustomControl2" but it's not and because of that, I get "multiple controls with ID CustomControl2 is found."  I know I can make CustomControl2 Id unique but what I don't understand is why the Id has not been embedded with the parent Id.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Do not confuse client-side IDs and server-side IDs. On client the IDs will be combined, but on server-side they will still have to be unique.

Comment: Let's see what momma has to say on the subject - see my example below for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to do this myself, turns out all you have to do is implement the `INamingContainer` "marker" interface on your web control. This will cause .net to generate an ID namespace for each instance of your control (which means all child controls will be prefixed with the parent control's ID as required).